# Can't run or debug the api locally

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I am following the quick start [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/quickstart-frameworks-java) tutorial and the api works online as it should. However, when it comes to testing the api locally, the admin server runs as it should but the api itself, which i supposed should be http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/echo/v1/echo and any post message should work. All I'm getting is : bad runtime process port [''].  I would also like to know how to create a debug configuration in eclipse as well as the api-explorer similar to what we used to have in v1.

Comment: Did you find any solution?